# How to specify schema location in an xsd file?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, xsd

I have an xsd file Foo.xsd. I tried following ways to refer it in a WSDL file but it doesnt work.

1) placed the xsd file in local file system and imported it as

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://ws.test.com/" schemaLocation="file:///D:/wsdl/Foo.xsd"></xsd:import>
```

2) Placed the xsd file in web root folder and imported as

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://ws.test.com/" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/Xfire/Foo.xsd"></xsd:import>
```

When I run the client I get null for the fields of response object. But this works when I embed the type definition inside the WSDL itself.

How do we specify the path to external xsds?

I am using xFire 1.2.6 for generating webservices. Client is generated using xFire WSGen ant task.

Comment: Be careful of build time versus run time paths if you reference the file directly. I had issues with this and ended up hosting xsds on a server for my references then referencing the uri instead.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The WSDL is accessed by HTTP from any host, so the client can neither access a file URL nor the localhost (which will be its own host, not your server). The best solution will be a file path to the xsd file:

Relative path:

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://ws.test.com/" schemaLocation="../Foo.xsd"/>
```

Absolute path:

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://ws.test.com/" schemaLocation="/myapp/Foo.xsd"/>
```

For the absolute path you need to know the context path of your webapp, so I would prefer the relative path.

Comment: tried the relative path using schemaLocation="/xfire/Foo.xsd"

org.codehaus.xfire.XFireRuntimeException: Couldn't find schema part: 

xFire 1.2.6 used for generating webservices.

Comment: A relative path does not start with a /. Is /xfire the context path of your webapp?

Comment: my project is maven Multi-module project I gave ../foo.xsd. If i build that module alone it is able to find XSD and build success. if I build from parent it is searching the XSD in parent root location, build is getting failed. any idea on how to give  xsd location if the project is multi module